# React props reusability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-reuse

I currently have a piece of code like this:

```js
    return (
        creatable
        ? <Select
            options={options}
            value={value}
            onChange={(selectedValue) => valueSetter(selectedValue)}
        />
        : <CreatableSelect
            options={options}
            value={value}
            onChange={(selectedValue) => valueSetter(selectedValue)}
        />
    )
```

As you can see, both of the components accept the exact same props. Is there any way that I can increase code reusability in this code (something like putting the props into a dictionary and unpack them)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can easily achieve this via the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Should look like this:

```
const props = {
   options,
   value,
   onChange: (selectedValue) => valueSetter(selectedValue)
}

return (
   creatable
      ? <Select {...props} />
      : <CreatableSelect {...props} />
)
```

What we do here is "spread" the content of a dedicated `props` object we've created and pass it to the target components.

Answer (score 1):

The @tomled answer is good. but we do not need redefine onChange function.

```
const props = {
   options,
   value,
   onChange: valueSetter
}

return (
   creatable
      ? <Select {...props} />
      : <CreatableSelect {...props} />
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd be careful with that. I've experienced some pitfalls with such implicit parameters. For example, It's a bit tricky to explain, but if you are using TypeScript for instance, and have a function that accepts an optional param, if you use that function in an HTML event (such as an `onClick` of a button element), and don't pass the optional parameter, the `event` itself will automatically be passed as the param, resulting in an unexpected value. I know it's a bit confusing, but I might be able to construct a `codesandbox` example if you're interested.